# Testflight not capturing the crash

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, crash-reports, beta-testing

Deployed build via TestFlight. Tester installed the app. For testing the crash report, I maiden the build with force crash code **fatalError()** on button click. It also happened, but the crash not reported in `iTunes connect or Xcode->Organizer`

[image]

The above screenshot shows the itunes connect status which didn't show the crash count.

**Note:**

1. My build is in beta. I have distributed to internal testers
   only.
2. Yet now, I didn't submit to the beta review(none of the previous build too), because, as of now, I don't need to
   distribute to the external tester.
3. I didn't do anything in Xcode for test flight setup.(Thought, it don't need).

If anyone experience with the same, please help me.

Comment: In my experience it can take up to 24h for crash reports to be available via TestFlight.

Comment: @Kerni Thanks for your info. I'll wait and see. Then update here about status.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **Share iPhone Analytics** and **Share With App Developers** are checked off under Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics & Improvements

And note that Apple says that some crashes (e.g. watchdog events, invalid code-signature crashes, thermal events, and high-memory use events) may not appear in the Crashes organizer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs

[image: Analytics & Improvements screen]